# Ported iPad App - App ID & provision profile should be the same?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I've just ported our iPhone app to iPad app (not using Universal). 
So, I'm about to submit the iPad app to the AppStore.
Here's my question:

Do I need to create another App ID & provision profiles for the iPad app equivalent?
Or I can just use the same App ID & provision profile being use in the iPhone app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new App ID for it.

Answer (score 0):

App IDs have to be unique.  If you want 2 separate apps in the store, you need 2 different App IDs.  And of course, the provisioning profiles have to be compatible with the IDs you use.  A wildcard profile might be compatible with more than one ID, if you choose them all correctly.